# Looking for the name of a sci-fi kids show from the late 90's / early 00's

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember watching it in the early 00's but I live in Argentina so it may be from the 90's.

The animation was early cg (I think it was a bit more polished than ReBoot but not by much).

It had a pulp look and feel with the basic concept being the dashing space captain fighting the evil green martians in his skin tight spacesuit.

The main character was a young white guy with black hair and at some point a Martian defector joined the team.

What triggered my memory was replaying *Fallout: New Vegas*, where the bright red ["space suit"](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Space_suit_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)) looks just like the one I remember the main character wearing.

[image: Fallout: New Vegas, Space suit]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! You have a nice start here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in any more details you may remember?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like "Dan Dare: Pilot of the Future". There's a picture of the main character and the alien defector here:

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0397775/

"The main character was a young white guy with black hair" - Well... young ISH, otherwise that's an accurate description of Dan.

"and at some point a Martian defector joined the team." - This character, Sondar, was actually Venusian. I believe he defected during the first story arc.

"The animation was early cg (I think it was a bit more polished than ReBoot but not by much)." - It was CG, and as it was a few years later than Reboot there would have been improvements in the technology since then.

"It had a pulp look and feel with the basic concept being the dashing space captain fighting the evil green martians in his skin tight spacesuit." - It was partly based on a comic series from the "pulp" era, and yep, that was pretty much the theme of the show. Except that they were Venusians.

I certainly do remember the spacesuits looking like your screenshot, but haven't found a picture to link to. There's a *partial* pic of a suited character here: https://joshuagamedesign.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/p2.png?w=300&h=209